# Issues with Three.Points; opacity, size and rotation

Tags: three.js, geometry, size, opacity, points

Yep, Another question about Three.points. I've been having issues for a while now trying to figure out how to adjust opacity, size and rotation for a while. I took a break to work on other areas of my code and I'm back to it.

My issue now is, after my previous question about it I've made a bit of progress with trying to get it to work but I've come across and issue with pushing the points out as I'm unfamiliar with this method or making particles happen.

This is a dumbed down version of my code, so hopefully it will get the point across;

```
var dirs = [], parts = [], container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild( container );
  var renderer, camera, scene
var cameramode, composer  
var particleSystem = [], particleCount = 15;
for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; ++ i) {
  var pgeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  var pMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("x.png"),
    blending: THREE.screenBlending,
    size: 60, depthTest: true,
    transparent: true, opacity: 1,
    depthTest: false, sizeAttenuation: true
  });
}

init();
animate();
update(); 

function init() {
 for (var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {
  pX = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1,
  pY = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1,
  pZ = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;
  var particle = new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ);
 }
 particle.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
 geometry.vertices.push(particle);
 var points = new THREE.Points(geometry, pMaterial);
 scene.add(points);
 particleSystem.push(points);
}

function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  controls.update(), composer.render();
  update(), render();
};

function update() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  while (pCount--) {
    var points   = particleSystem[i];

    if (particle.x < -150) {
      particle.z = (Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1)* 20;
      particle.x = (Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1)* 20;
      particle.velocity.x = 0, particle.velocity.y = 0, particle.velocity.z = 0};
    if (particle.z < -150) {
      particle.z = (Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1)* 20;
      particle.x = (Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1)* 20;
      particle.velocity.x = 0, particle.velocity.y = 0, particle.velocity.z = 0 };
    if (particle.y < -150) {
      particle.z = (Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1)* 20;
      particle.x = (Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1)* 20;
      particle.velocity.x = 0, particle.velocity.y = 0, particle.velocity.z = 0 };

    if (pCount%2 == 0){
      if (particle.x < 0){
        particle.velocity.x -= (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.002;
        particle.velocity.y -= (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.0001;
        particle.velocity.z -= (Math.sin(Math.random()*2))*0.001 };
      if (particle.x > 0){
        particle.velocity.x += (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.002;
        particle.velocity.y += (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.00001;
        particle.velocity.z -= (Math.random(Math.random()*2))*0.005 };
    } else {
      if (particle.x < 0){
        particle.velocity.z += (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.002;
        particle.velocity.y += (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.0001;
        particle.velocity.x -= (Math.random(Math.random()*2))*0.001 };
      if (particle.x > 0){
        particle.velocity.z -= (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.002;
        particle.velocity.y -= (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.00001;
        particle.velocity.x += (Math.random(Math.random()*2))*0.005 }};

    if (pCount%3 == 0){
      if (particle.velocity.z > 0){
        particle.velocity.y -= (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.0001;
        particle.velocity.x -= (Math.random(Math.random()*2))*0.005 };
      if (particle.velocity.z < 0){
        particle.velocity.y += (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.00001;
        particle.velocity.x -= (Math.random(Math.random()*2))*0.005 / 2}};
    if (pCount%5 == 0){
      if (particle.velocity.z > 0){
        particle.velocity.y -= (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.0001;
        particle.velocity.z += (Math.random(Math.random()*2))*0.005 };
      if (particle.velocity.z < 0){
        particle.velocity.y += (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.00001;
        particle.velocity.z += (Math.random(Math.random()*2))*0.005 }};
    if (pCount%7 == 0){
      if (particle.velocity.z > 0){
        particle.velocity.y -= (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.0001;
        particle.velocity.x -= (Math.random(Math.random()*2))*0.005};
      if (particle.velocity.z < 0){
        particle.velocity.y += (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))*0.00001;
        particle.velocity.x -= (Math.random(Math.random()*2))*0.005 / 2}};
  }

  particleSystem.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  particleSystem.rotation.y += (Math.random()*0.001)
} //animate end

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  update();
  composer.render(scene, camera);
});

function render()
{
  uniforms.tAudioData.value.needsUpdate = true;
  composer.render();
}
```

I keep having issues on addressing the location, the particle, point, ect and I'm not sure how to go about adjusting anything. My current issue is addressing the location of the points through this method in comparrision to;

```
for (var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {
  pX = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1,
  pY = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1,
  pZ = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1;
  var particle = new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ);
}
geometry.vertices.push(particle);
var points = new THREE.Points(geometry, pMaterial);
scene.add(points);
particleSystem.push(points);
```

which doesn't have any issues, but limits the functionality to only the positioning, velocity ect. There's probably a few other issues I'm causing that i'm not really aware of but how would I go about doing this or fixing the current issues that I'm having?

(A part 2 of this post: [.points opacity / size within three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786863/points-opacity-size-within-three-js))

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you still want to use `THREE.Geometry()` instead of `THREE.BufferGeometry()`? Using the last one, you'll be able to change any parameter on an individual point, using buffer attributes + `THREE.ShaderMaterial()`.

Comment: I'm familiar with it, that's the only reason why. What's the diffrences programming wise?

Comment: You will use shaders :)

Answer (score 0):

Just an example of using `THREE.BufferGeometry()` with attributes, instead of `THREE.Geometry()`.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 50);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var pointsDimension = 100;

var points = [];
var size = [];
var opacity = [];
var speed = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  points.push(new THREE.Vector3(
    Math.random(),
    Math.random(),
    Math.random()
  ).multiplyScalar(pointsDimension));
  size.push(Math.random() * 5 + 5);
  opacity.push(Math.random() * Math.PI);
  speed.push(Math.random() * 10 + 10);
}

var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
geom.addAttribute("size", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(size), 1));
geom.addAttribute("opacity", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(opacity), 1));
geom.addAttribute("speed", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(speed), 1));
geom.center();

var mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    time: {
      value: 0
    },
    color: {
      value: new THREE.Color(0x00ffff)
    },
    texture: {
      value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/sprites/snowflake2.png")
    }
  },
  vertexShader: `
    uniform float time;
    attribute float size;
    attribute float opacity;
    attribute float speed;
    varying float vOpacity;
    void main() {
      vOpacity = 1.0 - abs(sin(time + opacity));
      vec3 pos = position;
      pos.y = 50. - mod(50. - (position.y - (speed * time)), 100.);
      
      vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( pos, 1.0 );
      gl_PointSize = abs(sin(time + size)) * size * ( 300.0 / -mvPosition.z );
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    uniform sampler2D texture;
    uniform vec3 color;
    varying float vOpacity;
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4( color, vOpacity );
      gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
    }
  `,
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  depthTest: false,
  transparent: true
});

var particles = new THREE.Points(geom, mat);
scene.add(particles);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  mat.uniforms.time.value = clock.getElapsedTime();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's a no from me.

Comment: @Thea_Vore So, it's a no, but... Sooner or later you will come to this ;) If you really want to control attributes of particles ;)

Comment: @Thea_Vore The other (and inefficient) way is to use `THREE.Sprite()` as a particle, thus you'll be able to change its size and opacity individually.

Comment: I thought of that already but it would include me basically having to rewrite the whole thing. I would like to learn how to do... this... but it's just so forign idk where to start. Even from a quick copy paste, it doesn't work and as it's using a completely diffrent logic I'm familiar with, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: @Thea_Vore You have a working example here, also there are many examples on the official site of three.js, we have that forum, so there are so many helpful things you can use to achieve the desired result :) Yes, using of a buffer geometry seems harder and more complex than a usual geometry, but it's just at the beginning :)